# Problemas con consultas en mysql 5.6 (mysql)

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
ncuenta,dcuenta,
(select SUM(saldo) where saldo>0) debe,
(select sum(-saldo) where saldo<0) haber 
FROM tabla GROUP BY NCUENTA ORDER BY NCUENTA;
```

La cual me sirve pero en el `warmserver` versión del `mysql 5.7.19` 
y hace esto:

---

```
*********************************************************
|   ncuenta   |   dcuenta   |    debe     |    haber    |
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
|    101      |    BANCOS   |   16255.00  |    NULL     |
|_____________|_____________|_____________|_____________|
|   410-001   |   INGRESOS  |    NULL     |   5910.00   |
|_____________|_____________|_____________|_____________|
|   410-002   |    OTROS    |    NULL     |   12345.00  |
|_____________|_____________|_____________|_____________|
|   510-001   |   COMPRAS   |   1000.00   |    NULL     |
|_____________|_____________|_____________|_____________|
|   610-001   |   SALARIOS  |   1000.00   |   NULL      |
|_____________|_____________|_____________|_____________|
```

---

Que es exactamente lo que quiero.

Pero en el servidor web tengo la version 5.6.39 y cuando hago la consulta me sale:

> Error
>   consulta SQL: Documentación
>
> SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,(select SUM(saldo) where saldo>0) debe,
>   (select sum(-saldo) where saldo<0) haber FROM tabla GROUP BY NCUENTA ORDER BY NCUENTA LIMIT 0, 25
>   MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'where saldo>0) debe,
>   (select sum(-saldo) where saldo<0) haber FROM tables en la linea 1
>
> ---

Edito para dar mas información.

la base de datos contiene los siguientes datos:

...ncuenta
...dcuenta
......debe
......haber
......saldo


........101
.....BANCOS
....1234.00
.......0.00
....1234.00
....410-001
...INGRESOS
.......0.00
....1200.00
...-1200.00
........101
.....BANCOS
....1200.00
.......0.00
....1200.00
........101
.....BANCOS
......12.00
.......0.00
......12.00

y asi sucesivamente.
cuando hago la consulta en el warmserver (no se porque pero ahi si funciona la consulta no se si sera la version o que)

SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,
(select SUM(saldo) where saldo>0) debe,
(select sum(-saldo) where saldo<0) haber
 FROM tabla GROUP BY NCUENTA ORDER BY NCUENTA

.......101
....BANCOS
......2446 
.........0
......2446
 
...410-001 
..INGRESOS 
......0.00 
...1200.00 
..-1200.00

si aplico la misma consulta con la sugerencia que me estan dando entonces me hace que los campos debe y haber sean iguales osea me suma todos los campos saldo y me da el mismo resultado (si me sirve para otra cosa pero no para esta consulta )

Comment: Dale formato a tu código con el icono {} pues así no es legible

Comment: Por qué en una consulta usas LIMIT y en otra no?

Comment: ¿@Oscar Melendez estas seguro que te da ese resultado tal como dices en tu pregunta?

Comment: no tiene limit 1 uso la misma consulta pero en dos bases diferentes una en el wamrserver que tiene la version 5.7.19 y la otra en la pagina web que usa la version 5.6.39 porque en una si funciona y en otra no

Comment: Llama la atención que funciones estó `(select SUM(saldo) where saldo>0) debe`, prueba con `IF(saldo > 0, sum(saldo), 0) as debe`, de la misma forma con haber

Comment: @HammerffallBK Es por eso que le pregunte si estaba bien ya que la sintaxis te pediría un `FROM` de la tabla a la cual haces referencia.

Comment: No debe estar bien, pero tu dices que en wampserver con mysql 5.7.19 si te muestra resultado

Comment: Entonces como seria la sentencia para que me de los resultados

Comment: Ok voy a probar mañana esa sugerencia y les digo

Comment: Despúes de intentar con calma y paciencia ya pude hacer que me funcionara gracias por las ayudas a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haciendo la prueba, encontre otra solución

```
  select ncuenta, dcuenta, 
  sum(if(saldo > 0, saldo, 0)) as debe,
  sum(if(saldo < 0, -saldo, 0)) as haber 
  from cuentas group by ncuenta, dcuenta;
```

en el modo de `only_full_group_by` debe de agregarse los campos que tengamos seleccionados, de tal forma que hagan una combinación única, es decir; en el grupo habra varios valores para esa columna, pero solo habra espacio para mostrar una, por lo que debemos indicar como hacer esos valores únicos. [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una solución sencilla:

```
select ncuenta, dcuenta, 
  sum(if(saldo > 0, saldo, 0)) as debe,
  sum(if(saldo < 0, -saldo, 0)) as haber 
  from cuentas group by ncuenta, dcuenta;

only_full_group_by
```

Agrégale los campos seleccionados de tu consulta.